# No swap space on elementary-os Freya

Tags: release-freya, system-installation, boot, swap

During boot I get the message:

```
/dev/mapper/elementary--vg-swap_1 is not ready yet or not present - message on boot
```

which has been deleted after a while. After a login I can't see any swap space related entry in mtab. How can I solve this problem?

My system doesn't boot with UEFI, the content of the file fstab is

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.

 #

 # Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a

 # device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices

 # that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).

 #

 # <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
 /dev/mapper/elementary--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1

 # /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation

UUID=82b8b0b7-107b-4c99-89a5-1b0801c65e0b /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2

/dev/mapper/elementary--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0

/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0

/dev/sdb2 /opt ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,auto,user,exec,uhelper=udisks2 0 0

The results of the commands lsblk, pvs, vgs and lvs are

$ lsblk

NAME                             MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT

sda                                8:0    0 298.1G  0 disk 

├─sda1                             8:1    0   243M  0 part /boot

├─sda2                             8:2    0     1K  0 part 

└─sda5                             8:5    0 297.9G  0 part 

  ├─elementary--vg-root (dm-0)   252:0    0   282G  0 lvm  /

  └─elementary--vg-swap_1 (dm-1) 252:1    0  15.8G  0 lvm  

sdb                                8:16   0   2.7T  0 disk 

├─sdb1                             8:17   0     1M  0 part 

├─sdb2                             8:18   0   2.7T  0 part /opt

└─sdb3                             8:19   0  15.8G  0 part 

sdc                                8:32   0  37.3G  0 disk 

├─sdc1                             8:33   0  21.5G  0 part 

├─sdc2                             8:34   0     1K  0 part 

└─sdc5                             8:37   0  15.8G  0 part 

sr0                               11:0    1     2K  0 rom  

$ sudo pvs

[sudo] password for ralf: 

  PV         VG            Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree 

  /dev/sda5  elementary-vg lvm2 a--  297.85g 16.00m

$ sudo vgs

  VG            #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree 

  elementary-vg   1   2   0 wz--n- 297.85g 16.00m

$ sudo lvs

  LV     VG            Attr      LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Move Log Copy%  Convert

  root   elementary-vg -wi-ao--- 
282.03g                                           

  swap_1 elementary-vg -wi-a----  15.80g
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the UUID in `/etc/crypttab` in the line of cryptswad1? I think it is a known bug, you can replace the UUID by the device:

`cryptswap1 /dev/sdaX /dev/urandom swap,cipher=aes-cbc-essiv:sha256`

Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/472421

Comment: Unfortunately this hint don't help. I've read the source and changed the files  **crypttab** and **fstab** as suggested but after reboot the problem happens again.

Comment: I have tried to activate the swap space using **/etc/crypttab-early** but this fails again with the response **cryptswap1: the precheck for '/dev/sda5' failed: - The device /dev/sda5 contains a filesystem type LVM2member** :-/. Any suggestions how I can solve my problem?